# Need help to pre-process a dataset streamed on a TCP port in batches

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a beginner to Pyspark and I am trying to pre-process batches of streamed JSON strings into a format that can be fed into a machine learning model with the only constraint being that the model has to learn incrementally as the streamed data cannot be stored.
Here is an explanation of my current progress:

I have the twitter-sentiment dataset which I have cleaned and stored as a .csv file in my local system. Each record has two features:

1. **Sentiment**  --- > which is a single number: 0 for negative and 4 for positive.
2. **Text**   ---------- > the text of the tweet.

The python program mentioned below streams this dataset as JSON strings to a TCP port in batches. I have specified the .csv file and the batch size as command line arguments.
***Note:** I have included only the necessary code.*

**Stream.py :**

```
For TCP Connection:
    TCP_IP = "localhost"
    TCP_PORT = 6100

    def connectTCP():   
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        s.listen(1)
        print(f"Waiting for connection on port {TCP_PORT}...")
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connected to {address}")
        return connection, address
```

Code to stream data strings as json to the specified port:

```
def streamCSVFile(tcp_connection, input_file):

    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)  
    values = df.values.tolist()  

    # loop through batches of size batch_size lines
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(values) - batch_size + 2, batch_size)):
        send_data = values[i:i + batch_size]  # load batch of rows
        payload = dict()  # create a payload

        # iterate over the batch
        for mini_batch_index in range(len(send_data)):
            payload[mini_batch_index] = dict()  # create a record
            # iterate over the features
            for feature_index in range(len(send_data[0])):
                # add the feature to the record
                payload[mini_batch_index][f'feature{feature_index}'] = send_data[mini_batch_index][feature_index]
        send_batch = (json.dumps(payload) + '\n').encode()

        try:
            tcp_connection.send(send_batch)  # send the payload to Spark
        except BrokenPipeError:  # this indicates that the message length of the payload is more than what is allowed via TCP

            print("Either batch size is too big for the dataset or the connection was closed")
        except Exception as error_message:
            print(f"Exception thrown but was handled: {error_message}")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Given below is a simple code I have written to receive the streamed JSON and print the same on terminal.

**rec.py :**

```
import socket
import json

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 6100

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(repr(data))

s.close()
```

The above code works fine but what I want to achieve is to get the JSON object for the batch read from the stream and convert this object into a rdd or dataframe on which I can perform transformations. (For example filtering hashtag values and grouping by them).

Screenshot of the dataset (For reference):

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a solution for my problem and hence came back to suggest my idea.
Here is how I collected the streamed data:

```
def get_training_data(data, dataset=None):
    values = list()
    for record_index in data:
      record = data[record_index]
      record_values = list(record.values())
      values.append(np.asarray(record_values))
    values = np.asarray(values)
    return values

def process_stream(batch):
    data = batch.collect()
    if not data:
        return
    data = data[0]
    data = json.loads(data)
    values = get_training_data(data)
   
data_stream = spark_streaming_context.socketTextStream("localhost", 6100).foreachRDD(process_stream)
spark_streaming_context.start()
spark_streaming_context.awaitTermination(1000)
spark_streaming_context.stop()
```

Now, if you want to work on a `dataframe` you can achieve the same with:

```
def convert_data_to_df(data):
    # Specifying the datatype of each column
    SCHEMA = StructType(
        [
            StructField("attr_0", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_1", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_2", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_3", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_4", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_5", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_6", StringType()),
            StructField("attr_7", DoubleType()),
            StructField("attr_8", DoubleType())
        ]
    )

    DF_COLUMNS = ["Dates","Category","Descript","DayOfWeek","PdDistrict","Resolution","Address","X","Y"]

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=SCHEMA).toDF(*DF_COLUMNS)
```

In order to extract `x coordinates` and `y coordinates` needed for training:

```
    x_columns = ["X","Y","DayOfWeek","PdDistrict","Hour","Month","Year"]                    
    coordinate_x = np.asarray(df.select(x_columns).collect())
    coordinate_y = np.asarray(df.select("Category").collect())                   
    coordinate_y = column_or_1d(coordinate_y, warn=True)
```

Using these parameters, the classification/clustering model can be incrementally trained.

Answer (score 0):

You write the JSON line-wise - therefore you need also read the JSON line-wise and not in chunks of 1024 bytes.